# How to duplicate element content using onclick in jquery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Every time i clicked on any h5 tag it always insert the first h5 which is "First Trial" in below example, i need to print the rest of tags if clicked on it carrying the same class or ID if needed to add.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5 class="trial" style="cursor: pointer;">First Trial</h5>
<h5 class="trial" style="cursor: pointer;">Second Trial</h5>
<h5 class="trial" style="cursor: pointer;">Third Trial</h5>
<h5 class="trial" style="cursor: pointer;">Fourth Trial</h5>
<h5 class="trial" style="cursor: pointer;">Fifth Trial</h5>
<h4 class="final"></h4>


<script>
  $('.trial').click(function() {
    $('.final').html($('.trial').html());
  });
</script>
```

Comment: "_the same class or ID_" `id`s must be unique within the document.

Comment: [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/): _"Get the HTML contents of the **first element** in the set of matched elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element."_

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/)

Comment: `$('.final').html($(this).html());`

Comment: It always take first element found in the DOM. So either you need to use for loop or you can also try <script>
  $('.trial').click(function(event) {
    $('.final').html($(event.currentTarget).html());
  });
</script>

Comment: It's unclear what is the expected result. **Clone** an element or **move** it to a new container parent?

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks bro this fixed my issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, the secret was about "This", because it picks the content of element i clicked on not the content of the first element.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the completeness a plain JavaScript solution for those, who don 't want a dependency to jQuery or just want to get rid of jQuery in 2021.

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.trial'),
    container = document.querySelector('.final');

elements.forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', event => {
    container.append(event.currentTarget.cloneNode(true));
}));
```

```html
<h5 class="trial" style="cursor: pointer;">First Trial</h5>
<h5 class="trial" style="cursor: pointer;">Second Trial</h5>
<h5 class="trial" style="cursor: pointer;">Third Trial</h5>
<h5 class="trial" style="cursor: pointer;">Fourth Trial</h5>
<h5 class="trial" style="cursor: pointer;">Fifth Trial</h5>
<h4 class="final"></h4>
```

This snippet adds an event listener to every h5.trial element. You should avoid that. Better practice: Add a single event listener to a parent element, that contains the elements you want to observe.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element which has click by `$(this)` in your event handler, Then make clone of clicked element and append it to the `.final` element, like this:

```js
$('.trial').click(function() {
  $('.final').append($(this).clone())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5 class="trial" style="cursor: pointer;">First Trial</h5>
<h5 class="trial" style="cursor: pointer;">Second Trial</h5>
<h5 class="trial" style="cursor: pointer;">Third Trial</h5>
<h5 class="trial" style="cursor: pointer;">Fourth Trial</h5>
<h5 class="trial" style="cursor: pointer;">Fifth Trial</h5>
<h4 class="final"></h4>
```

If you want to allways show just last element which has clicked, you can change your script like this:

```
$('.trial').click(function() {
  $('.final').html($(this).clone())
});
```